# Range Query on a score returned by match Query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Suppose I have a set of documents like :-

```
    {
       "Name":"Random String 1"
       "Type":"Keyword"
       "City":"Lousiana"
       "Quantity":"10"
    }
```

Now I want to implement a full text search using an N-gram analyazer on the field Name and City.

After that , I want to filter only the results returned with

```
    "_score" :<Query Score Returned by ES>
```

greater than 1.2 (Maybe By Range Query Aggregation Method)

And after that apply term aggregation method on the property: "Type" and then return the top results in each bucket by using "top_hits" aggregation method. 
How can I do so ?

I've been able to implement everything apart from the Range Query on score returned by a search query.

Comment: can you show us ur mappings?

Comment: The dummy data I gave is not the exact data that I am using for my project , but yes , the mapping down below provided by you is kinda what I am using with the similar analyzer. I am just using a different search analyzer which is a standard analayzer

Comment: @AyushAggarwal Did you find any solution? I am stuck with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to score the documents organically then i you can use [min_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html) in query to filter the matched documents for the score.

for ngram analyer i added whitespace tokenizer and a lowercase filter

**Mappings**

```
PUT index1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "edge_n_gram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter" : ["lowercase",  "ednge_gram_filter"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
      "ednge_gram_filter" : {
        "type" : "NGram",
        "min_gram" : 2,
        "max_gram": 10
      }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "document_type" : {
      "properties": {
        "Name" : {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "edge_n_gram_analyzer"
        },
        "City" : {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "edge_n_gram_analyzer"
        },
        "Type" : {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Document**

```
POST index1/document_type
{
       "Name":"Random String 1",
       "Type":"Keyword",
       "City":"Lousiana",
       "Quantity":"10"
}
```

**Query**

```
POST index1/_search
{
  "min_score": 1.2,
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Name": {
              "value": "string"
          }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "City": {
              "value": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "type_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Type",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "type_term_top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: See here you took the min_score as a static value. So the point I had is that I am unure what the document score would be and hence I would like to implement a range query on a score returned by it . 

**Can I fetch the _score dynamically and refer it inside a query ?**